# Keeping cat safe and comfortable while moving

Tags: cats, house-moving

I will be moving to a new apartment in a few weeks. I have an indoor-only cat who has never been outside. I understand how to acclimatize her to the new apartment by slowly introducing her to new areas. However, I'm concerned about the logistics of the move itself.

My apartment is not huge, and there is no good area to put her where there won't be movers. I'm concerned about her getting out if they leave a door open, that she might get stuck somewhere while they're moving, and that she'll be generally uncomfortable and on edge for hours.

I was considering taking her to a cat hotel (such as https://www.catsonlyboarding.com/) overnight during the move. While she definitely doesn't like getting in her carrier and going in the car, I thought it might be better to have her in a safe and comfortable location during the move.

Are there any suggestions on the best way to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's extremely important to keep your cat confined while the movers are at work. Her escaping the apartment is not the only hazard; she could also be stepped on by a worker, or something they are moving could be dropped on her, causing severe injury or death.

Most cats don't care for carriers, but consider that one brief period of discomfort is better than loss, injury or death. If the apartment is extremely small, consider confining her to the bathroom (and letting the movers know that they are not to open the door--taping a sign to the door would not be a bad idea). Make sure you don't open the bathroom door unless the exit to the apartment is fully closed, with no one coming in or out of it. She won't be happy, but she'll be safe, and she'll get over it in a few days.

If you're not comfortable that the bathroom can be closed up sufficiently to keep her contained for the entire time the movers are working, a cat hotel would be a good substitute. Again, she may not be happy right away (most cats don't like being put in their carriers or in the car, as it's typically a prelude to the vet for them), but she'll be fine in a few days.

Source: I have moved with my own cats several times, they're always fine after a day or two of settling in, even when being left in "scary" (to them) rooms during the move.

Comment: +1 and I might consider splitting the difference and take her to the cat hotel for the day and pick her up after the movers leave. Before picking her up, prepare her “area,” food dishes, litter box, cat tree, etc. It’s CRUCIAL to have a place she can “escape” to preferably some place high. I have installed cat shelves near my cats tall cat tree so they can be “above it all.”

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations folks. I took yours advice of your second paragraph and confined her to the large walk-in closet, and made the movers well aware to not open the door. I provided all of her necessities there, and while she wasn't "happy", she was safe. When I brought her to the new place, I initially kept her in the bedroom as a "safe space" with high areas, low areas and other hiding spaces. She is now mostly content with the new place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I saw many owners moved to their new home where haven't installed the net on the window, they would buy a big [cat cage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019OQ14LE) and put all the cat supplies in the cage, including a food bowl, water bowl, litter box, cat hammock bed, and toys.

If you will live in the new apartment when the movers work, I suggest you put your cat in a cage and settle the cage in a peaceful place. She will feel nervous and timid in a new place, so you should usually comfort her and distract her attention. Unlock her after making sure the window and balcony have been netted.

In fact, she would also feel nervous in a cat hotel due to a strange environment. Therefore, living in a cage may benefit to apply to the new home in advance.